# FireDAC: Shared Lock on Table with Firebird

Tags: firebird, delphi-10.1-berlin, firedac

I'm using Delphi 10.1 with FireDAC to connect to Firebird.

I would like to open a table in Exclusive mode in Firebird with FireDAC?
How would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird does not handle table or row locks. So there's no way you're going to get this to work with FireDAC... no connection parameters can do this magic.

What you can do with Firebird is to use the entire database in single user mode. To do this, you must shut it down, run GFIX to flag it as a single user database, and then reconnect to the database. You can find more details on [the Firebird How-To FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq131/). But I doubt this is what you are looking for.

You should explain better what you are trying to do. With real SQL servers you should not feel the need to lock tables or rows. Transactions and transaction isolation should be enough to handle most situations. If not, then you should probably start thinking about application level locks, that is, if you have just one application that uses the database.

Comment: FireDAC doesn't support using table reservation (see [`SET TRANSACTION`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-transacs-statements.html#fblangref25-transacs-settransac))?

Comment: @Mark, not natively (at this time; additional way of transaction control through the `TxOptions.Params` collection is fixed for declared constant parameter array).